# How to find difference between two date time in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have the following datatype:

```
id=["Train A","Train A","Train A","Train B","Train B","Train B"]
arrival_time = ["0"," 2016-05-19 13:50:00","2016-05-19 21:25:00","0","2016-05-24 18:30:00","2016-05-26 12:15:00"]
departure_time = ["2016-05-19 08:25:00","2016-05-19 16:00:00","2016-05-20 07:45:00","2016-05-24 12:50:00","2016-05-25 23:00:00","2016-05-26 19:45:00"]
```

To obtain the following data:

```
id              arrival_time                departure_time
Train A                 0                  2016-05-19 08:25:00
Train A          2016-05-19 13:50:00       2016-05-19 16:00:00
Train A          2016-05-19 21:25:00       2016-05-20 07:45:00
Train B                    0               2016-05-24 12:50:00
Train B          2016-05-24 18:30:00       2016-05-25 23:00:00
Train B          2016-05-26 12:15:00       2016-05-26 19:45:00
```

The datatype of departure time and arrival time is datetime64[ns].

How to find the time difference between 1st row departure time and 2nd row arrival time ? I tired the following code and it didnt work. For example to find the time difference between [2016-05-19 08:25:00] and [2016-05-19 13:50:00].

```
df['Duration'] = df.departure_time.iloc[i+1] - df.arrival_time.iloc[i]
```

Comment: This question gets asked a lot but +1 for neatly giving your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need first convert `dates` string [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), also `0` has to be convert to `NaN`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': id, 'arrival_time':arrival_time, 'departure_time':departure_time})

df['arrival_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['arrival_time'].replace('0', np.nan))
#another solution for replace not dates to NaT
#df['arrival_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['arrival_time'], errors='coerce')
df['departure_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['departure_time'])
print (df)
         arrival_time      departure_time       id
0                 NaT 2016-05-19 08:25:00  Train A
1 2016-05-19 13:50:00 2016-05-19 16:00:00  Train A
2 2016-05-19 21:25:00 2016-05-20 07:45:00  Train A
3                 NaT 2016-05-24 12:50:00  Train B
4 2016-05-24 18:30:00 2016-05-25 23:00:00  Train B
5 2016-05-26 12:15:00 2016-05-26 19:45:00  Train B
```

Then [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) column `departure_time` per group `id` with `groupby` and substract `arrival_time` column.

```
df['Duration'] = df.groupby('id')['departure_time'].shift() - df['arrival_time']
print (df)
         arrival_time      departure_time       id          Duration
0                 NaT 2016-05-19 08:25:00  Train A               NaT
1 2016-05-19 13:50:00 2016-05-19 16:00:00  Train A -1 days +18:35:00
2 2016-05-19 21:25:00 2016-05-20 07:45:00  Train A -1 days +18:35:00
3                 NaT 2016-05-24 12:50:00  Train B               NaT
4 2016-05-24 18:30:00 2016-05-25 23:00:00  Train B -1 days +18:20:00
5 2016-05-26 12:15:00 2016-05-26 19:45:00  Train B -1 days +10:45:00
```

Or maybe need swap columns for positive timedelta:

```
df['Duration'] = df['arrival_time'] - df.groupby('id')['departure_time'].shift()
print (df)
         arrival_time      departure_time       id  Duration
0                 NaT 2016-05-19 08:25:00  Train A       NaT
1 2016-05-19 13:50:00 2016-05-19 16:00:00  Train A  05:25:00
2 2016-05-19 21:25:00 2016-05-20 07:45:00  Train A  05:25:00
3                 NaT 2016-05-24 12:50:00  Train B       NaT
4 2016-05-24 18:30:00 2016-05-25 23:00:00  Train B  05:40:00
5 2016-05-26 12:15:00 2016-05-26 19:45:00  Train B  13:15:00
```

Last is possible convert `timedelta` to `seconds` by [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
df['Duration'] = (df['arrival_time'] - df.groupby('id')['departure_time'].shift()).dt.total_seconds()
print (df)
         arrival_time      departure_time       id  Duration
0                 NaT 2016-05-19 08:25:00  Train A       NaN
1 2016-05-19 13:50:00 2016-05-19 16:00:00  Train A   19500.0
2 2016-05-19 21:25:00 2016-05-20 07:45:00  Train A   19500.0
3                 NaT 2016-05-24 12:50:00  Train B       NaN
4 2016-05-24 18:30:00 2016-05-25 23:00:00  Train B   20400.0
5 2016-05-26 12:15:00 2016-05-26 19:45:00  Train B   47700.0
```

Comment: Do you know how i can get the maximum and minimum value of "duration" ??

Comment: Try `print (df['Duration'].max())` and `print (df['Duration'].min())`

Comment: Also, is it possible to view the complete row with the maximum and minimum duration?

Comment: Yes, try `print (df.loc[df['Duration'].idxmin()])` and `print (df.loc[df['Duration'].idxmax()])`

Comment: I tried it! i tried with "argmax" also. I get the error : ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1 days 04:37:27.518580000

Comment: It seems iit is buggy for `timedeltas`, so need convert to int first `print (df.loc[df['Duration'].dt.total_seconds().idxmin()])`

Comment: Thank you! i tried it after converting time to timedelta function! and now it works!!!

Comment: Supeer, nice day!

Comment: Is there a option to get the time difference as a positive number ?? (to convert negative answers to positive!?)

Comment: I think the simpliest is add `abs` - `df['Duration'] = (df['arrival_time'] - df.groupby('id')['departure_time'].shift()).dt.total_seconds().abs()`

Comment: I test it, `df['Duration'] = (df.groupby('id')['departure_time'].shift() - df['arrival_time']).abs()` works also nice.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. it works. i got answer as 03:12:37.771200. is there an option to remove the seconds and microseconds as well ?

Comment: Yes, hmmm, it seems not so easy. Get me  asec.

Comment: You can use `df['Duration'] = df['Duration'].values.astype("timedelta64[m]")`

Comment: Yes, Iris, maybe better is create new questions ;) If you have time, you can create question for last comment, I think it is interesting solution (not easy) and then can help another people. But it is up to you ;)

Comment: @jezrael I've been trying to difference two datetime64 objects in pandas but have been getting NaTs - yours is the only way I have found to get it right after an hour of searching - is this a Q&A in its own right?

Comment: Yes, I create answer.

Comment: @jezrael see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730272/pandas-difference-of-of-two-datetime64-objects-yields-nat-rather-than-correct-t